# Laravel Eloquent Relationship column not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Can you help me with this one?

**ANSWER MODEL**

```
class Answer extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    protected $table = 'answers';
    protected $fillable = array('customerID', 'agentID', 'status', 'date', 'urn_code', 'urn_id');

    public function customer(){
        return $this->hasOne('Customer');
    }
}
```

**CUSTOMER MODEL**

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    protected $table = 'leads';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cID';

    protected $fillable =  array('cID','title', 'first_name','last_name','address1', 'address2', 'post_code','city','phone_number');

    public function answers() {
        return $this->hasMany('Answer');
    }
}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('sales', function(){
    $sales = Customer::with('answers')->get()->paginate(15);

    foreach($sales as $sale)
    echo $sale->last_name . '<br />'; 

});
```

and this is my error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answers.customer_id'
```

Comment: Can you show also migration for your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly how the error says. In your `answers` table, Laravel is looking for a `customer_id` column automatically, and it doesn't exist in this case.

If your customer ID column is under a different name, you can specify it as the second parameter in the `hasMany()` method:

```
public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Answer', 'my_column');
}
```

Also, you should probably be using a `belongsTo` relationship here, as pointed out by @razor.

Comment: Also, in `Answer` model, it should be `belongsTo()`(not `hasOne()`) in `customer()` relation

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using custom primary keys, you need to specify the local key and the foreign key.

```
public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Answer', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

Probably you'll have to update your Answer model as well (please, check out if you really need a hasOne or a belongsTo relation):

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

You can find more info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).